# Spring ControllerAdvice not firing for some exceptions but others

Tags: java, spring, exception, controller

I have a springboot rest service that can be accessed through the `/test` endpoint. I have setup a error handling controller like so:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class AppErrorController extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidHeaderException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<JsonNode> handleHeaderError(InvalidHeaderException ex) {
        return ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
                .body(generateResponseJson(ex));
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidRequestException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<JsonNode> handleRequestError(InvalidRequestException ex) {
        return ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
                .body(generateResponseJson(ex));
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ServiceResponseException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<JsonNode> handleServiceError(ServiceResponseException ex) {
        return ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .body(generateResponseJson(ex));
    }

    private JsonNode generateResponseJson(Exception ex) {
        return ResponseBuilder.newBuilder()
                .withException(ex.getClass().getSimpleName())
                .withDescription(ex.getMessage())
                .withTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now())
                .buildAsJson();
    }
}
```

I've tested this out and this works perfectly fine. If I test the api with a bad input then it returns:

```
{
  "exception": "InvalidRequestException",
  "description": "A valid input value is needed that is non-empty or non-null.",
  "timestamp": "2016-03-28T11:35:39.765"
}
```

And this is what the log looks like in correlation with the `AppErrorController` handling the exception:

```
11:35:39.706 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'Foo_Engine' processing POST request for [/test]
11:35:39.706 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /test
11:35:39.707 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode> controllers.FooController.getFoosForRest(controllers.model.Request,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)]
11:35:39.708 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor - Read [class controllers.model.Request] as "application/json" with [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@3086f443]
11:35:39.709 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode> controllers.FooController.getFoosForRest(controllers.model.Request,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)]: controllers.exceptions.InvalidRequestException: A valid input value is needed that is non-empty or non-null.
11:35:39.761 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'appErrorController'
11:35:39.762 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Invoking @ExceptionHandler method: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode> controllers.AppErrorController.handleRequestError(controllers.exceptions.InvalidRequestException)
11:35:39.815 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor - Written [{"resultCode":false,"exception":"InvalidRequestException","description":"A valid input value is needed that is non-empty or non-null.","timestamp":"2016-03-28T11:35:39.765"}] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@3086f443]
11:35:39.816 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'Foo_Engine': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
11:35:39.816 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

This works great when with the `InvalidHeaderException` and `InvalidRequestException` but for some reason it doesn't work for `ServiceResponseException`. The first exception gets thrown by a header interceptor, the second gets thrown by the controller sitting up top and the 3rd one gets thrown by the inner code. Here is where it gets thrown:

```
public class Foo {
    private final Cache<String, List<Foo>> fooCache;

    public Foo() {
        fooCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build();
    }

    public List<Foo> getFoo() {
        List<Foo> foos = null;
        try {
            foos = fooCache.get(foo.getId(),
                    () -> populateCacheWithFoo());
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return foos;
    }

    public List<Foo> populateCacheWithFoo() {
        JsonNode response = null;
        try {
            response = operation.postForObject(/* resource url */,
                    /* build header body */,
                    JsonNode.class);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new ServiceResponseException("Error with backend service - getResourceA operation");
        }

        List<Foo> foos = response.get("Foos");

        fooCache.put(foo.get(1).getId(), foos);
        return foos;
    }
}
```

For some reason, whenever I throw this exception it just doesn't get caught by the `AppErrorController` and instead I get this stack trace:

```
11:23:43.085 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode> controllers.FooController.getFoosForRest(controllers.model.Request,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)]: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: controllers.exceptions.ServiceResponseException: Error with backend service - getResourceA operation
11:23:43.086 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode> controllers.FooController.getFoosForRest(controllers.model.Request,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)]: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: controllers.exceptions.ServiceResponseException: Error with backend service - getResourceA operation
11:23:43.086 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode> controllers.FooController.getFoosForRest(controllers.model.Request,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)]: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: controllers.exceptions.ServiceResponseException: Error with backend service - getResourceA operation
11:23:43.096 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Could not complete request
com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: controllers.exceptions.ServiceResponseException: Error with backend service - getResourceA operation
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2207)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3953)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4790)
    at services.Foo.getFoo(IdentityClientImpl.java:73)
    at controllers.FooController.getFoosForRest(FooController.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:871)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:95)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: controllers.exceptions.ServiceResponseException: Error with backend service - getResourceA operation
    at services.Foo.populateCacheWithFoo(Foo.java:99)
    at services.Foo.lambda$getFoo$0(Foo.java:74)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4793)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3542)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2323)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2286)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2201)
    ... 56 common frames omitted
```

Any idea why the first 2 exceptions are getting caught by the `AppErrorController` but not the 3rd one? Is there some configuration I need to do in my java config files? Here's my mvc configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    ServletContext servletContext;

    @Autowired
    HeaderInterceptor interceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getJspViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/jsp/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is ```ServiceResponseException``` a subclass of ```ExecutionException``` ?

Comment: @maximede actually no, it extends `RuntimeException`. Should it extend `ExecutionException`? The other 2 exceptions extend from `RuntimeException` as well

Comment: nope, I was just afraid the ```ServiceResponseException``` might be caught  in your ```public List<Foo> getFoo``` method

Comment: @maximede actually if you look at the stacktrace it has google cache in the trace. I breakpointed and stepped through and found that the `ServiceResponseException` gets caught by a catch statement inside the google cache api. That could be the problem but I have no idea how to make it so that the it doesn't get caught by the google code and rather my `AppErrorController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the problem is that the `Callable` in the guava get cache catch the exception and re-throw them encapsulated : http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#get(K,%20java.util.concurrent.Callable)

You might want to add a catch clause in your `getFoo()` method and re-throw the original exception.
Something like this :

```
public List<Foo> getFoo() throws ServiceResponseException{
    List<Foo> foos = null;
    try {
        foos = fooCache.get(foo.getId(),
                () -> populateCacheWithFoo());
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        Throwables.propagateIfPossible(
        e.getCause(), ServiceResponseException.class);
    } 
    return foos;
}
```

But you might want to put a breakpoint in the catch to confirm that the `.getCause()` is your actual exception or if it's a level bellow

---

Or you could do this if you don't want to change your `ServiceException` to a checked exception :

```
public List<Foo> getFoo() throws ServiceResponseException{
    List<Foo> foos = null;
    try {
        foos = fooCache.get(foo.getId(),
                () -> populateCacheWithFoo());
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UncheckedExecutionException e) {
        Throwables.propagateIfPossible(
        e.getCause(), ServiceResponseException.class);
    } 
    return foos;
}
```

Comment: it gives me an error and says `Exception com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException has already been caught`

Comment: Just read a bit more about Guava, and I think the easiest way to fix your problem would be to make your ```ServiceResponseException``` a checked exception ( by extending ```Exception``` instead of ```RuntimeException``` ) And by adapting your code to look like my edited answer

Comment: I changed it to extend `Exception` and now I'm getting this error: `java: unreported exception controllers.exceptions.ServiceResponseException; must be caught or declared to be thrown`

Comment: you'll need to change the signature of getFoo to ```public List<Foo> getFoo() throws ServiceResponseException```

Comment: I'm not sure I want to go down this solution. I have to change a huge portion of the code base to add ` throws ServiceResponseException` since this method is used a lot everywhere else. Is this the only way?

Comment: What was saying ```Exception com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException has already been caught``` when you were catching the ```UncheckedExecutionException``` ? Just tried on my machine and I was able to  do a ```catch (UncheckedExecutionException ue)``` and print the cause

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107573/discussion-between-maximede-and-richard).

Comment: It just keeps getting caught by google's cache catch block. No matter how many combinations of `propagate` i use it just refuses to be handled by the controller.